# How can I use String in enum for Apex?

Tags: apex, enum

I have created one static string in apex like

```
private static string HARSWARE_SOFTWARE= 'Hardware and Software';
```

and now this variable I am using in ENum like

```
public Enum PSServices{HARSWARE_SOFTWARE}
```

But when i print the service then I am getting variable `HARSWARE_SOFTWARE` not value?

In Java we can write

```
public Enum PSServices{HARSWARE_SOFTWARE('Hardware and Software')}
```

But same when i tried in salesforce apex i am getting error, I want string as return type.

Please assist me in this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's just not how [enums work in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_enums.htm):

> Although each value corresponds to a distinct integer value, the enum hides this implementation so that you don’t inadvertently misuse the values, such as using them to perform arithmetic. After you create an enum, variables, method arguments, and return types can be declared of that type.

and note that

> Unlike Java, the enum type itself has no constructor syntax.

You should treat enums in Apex as abstract, valueless identifiers only. The value `PSServices.HARSWARE_SOFTWARE` is distinct from the variable `HARSWARE_SOFTWARE` existing in the outer scope.

Comment: So u mean I can't access the variable value which  I have passed. I need to create a list of string rather than use ENUM with static variable?

Comment: @user69533 You cannot create enums with specific values at all. If you want to store string values, you'll need to use `String`-typed variables.